# Смена иконки кнопки toolbar'a в AlertDialog "Cannot resolve symbol"

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-menu

Всем привет!
Столкнулся с невозможностью сменить иконку кнопки тулбара в алертдиалоге. ("Cannot resolve symbol"). Пробовал объявлять кнопку в других местах, результата не дало. Прошу помочь.

```
//меню
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    MenuItem mChangeCur = menu.findItem(R.id.change_cur);
    mChangeCur.setIcon(R.drawable.usd);

    MenuItem mSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) mSearch.getActionView();
    mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search");

    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

// обработка нажатий меню
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.change_cur:
            // setup the alert builder
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Choose currency");
            // add a list
            String[] currencies = {"USD", "RUB", "AUD", "BRL", "CAD"};
            builder.setItems(currencies, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            cur = "USD";
                            new Refresh().execute();
                            mChangeCur.setIcon(R.drawable.rub); //ошибка
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            cur = "RUB";
                            new Refresh().execute();
                            mChangeCur.setIcon(R.drawable.rub);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                        case 3:
                        case 4:

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Нужен полный стактрейс ошибки

Comment: Error:(103, 33) error: cannot find symbol variable mChangeCur
При этом кнопка объявлена выше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mChangeCur` - это переменная объявленная в методе. Следовательно область её видимости - это метод, в котором она объявлена. Для решения вашей проблемы вам необходимо разделить объявление и инициализацию переменной, причём объявление должно быть на уровне класса (чтобы был к ней доступ из всех методов этого класса).

Если это выражать в коде, то будет так:

```
MenuItem mChangeCur;

//меню
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    mChangeCur = menu.findItem(R.id.change_cur);

    ...

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

// обработка нажатий меню
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.change_cur:
            // setup the alert builder
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Choose currency");
            // add a list
            String[] currencies = {"USD", "RUB", "AUD", "BRL", "CAD"};
            builder.setItems(currencies, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            cur = "USD";
                            new Refresh().execute();
                            mChangeCur.setIcon(R.drawable.rub); //ошибка
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            cur = "RUB";
                            new Refresh().execute();
                            mChangeCur.setIcon(R.drawable.rub);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                        case 3:
                        case 4:

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Не догадался сам разделить инициализацию и объявление. Все работает.